# Make CSS transition fade out after hovered for long enough

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am building a slideshow for a website homepage. I built arrow buttons that appear when the slideshow is hovered using CSS. But one feature I think would be cool is the ability for, after a period of time, the mouse disappears and the buttons fade away. I'm fine with answers using JS or CSS. Here is my code:

```css
.master {
 display: none;
 width: 100vw;
}

.mcont {
 background-image: url("../Pictures/magtrans.jpg");
 padding: auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center;
}

.hover {
 height: 100vh;
}

.mtext {
 color: #ffffff;
 display: table;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 margin: auto;
 padding: 3vw;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

.mtext h1 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding-bottom: 1vh;
 font-size: 5vh;
}

.mtext p {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding-bottom: 2.5vh;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2vh;
}

.mtext button {
 background-color: #5555ff;
 border: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 15px 32px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 outline: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
 transition: background-color 2s;
}

.mtext button:hover {
 background-color: #55aaff;
}

.leftc, .rightc {
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 5vw;
 height: 5vw;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 vertical-align: middle;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 3vw;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
 transition: opacity 1s;
}

.hover:hover > .leftc {
 opacity: 1.0;
}

.hover:hover > .rightc {
 opacity: 1.0;
}

.leftc {
 left: 1vw;
}

.rightc {
 right: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class='mcont'>
  <img class='master' src='Media/Pictures/magtrans.jpg'/>
 <div class='hover'>
  <button class='leftc'><</button>
  <button class='rightc'>></button>
  <div class='mtext'>
   <h1>Slideshow</h1>
   <p>Buttons to left and right!</p>
   <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

What I need is something like in Google Slides, where the cursor and toolbar fades away after a few seconds and comes back when the mouse moves. I have done extensive research on CSS transitions and animations. Animating `cursor` would work, but `cursor` is not animatable.

Comment: Even though you are sharing some code, it has nothing to do with the requirement and you made 0 prgress (and no coding attempt) towards your goal. Which makes you a client asking for free work. If you don't want this status, change it: (re)search, have an attempt at coding it, ask us why some CSS or JS does not do what you think it should, even though docs lead you to believe it should, etc... SO is not a free coding service. In short, we're just a bunch of programmers teaching each other tricks and coding best practices. We're not here to work.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I thoroughly researched CSS transitions and animations, and found nothing. But I certainly agree, SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: That's because you can't use CSS to run code on mouse move. You have to use Javascript for it. Simplest solution is to add/remove a class on mouse move.

Comment: You're right, I probably should have researched/tried some JS before I asked on SO. I was just hoping there was some obvious answer I had missed somewhere, and that I would't spend a half hour programming JS for something you can do with three lines of CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The theory

The CSS states (usable to style things up based on element state - hence based on user interaction) are:

```
:hover         :active        :focus         :target        :link
```

To this you can add the validation pseudo-classes

```
:checked       :valid         :invalid       :default       :disabled
:empty         :enabled       :optional      :in-range      :out-of-range
:read-only     :read-write    :required      :indeterminate
```

You also have the structural pseudo-classes (`:nth-*`, `:first-*`, `:last-*`), a few experimental and miscellaneous ones:

```
:scope         :dir           :lang          :root          :fullscreen
```

...and, of course, the pseudo-elements (`:before` & `:after`).

If you want anything that cannot be reduced to a combination of the above, you're on JavaScript territory, because you want make DOM modification based on user interactions, other than the native (above) ones. Also note not all of the above are implemented by all browsers.

Your request is not doable with CSS alone because you want to display `:hover` state differently based on whether or not the mouse moved over the past `Nms`.

## The practice (JS solution)

The simplest solution is to display your arrows when a particular class (`active`) is present on the parent. Add that class to the parent on `mousemove` event and debounce the execution of a function (which removes the class) by the desired interval. If a `mousemove` happens during the debounce period,  the debounced function is canceled and a brand new instance of it is created. In the example below the debounce interval is `1s`:

```js
let deactivate = debounce(function() {
  document.querySelector('.mcont').classList.remove('active');
}),
 activate = function() {
  document.querySelector('.mcont').classList.add('active');
  deactivate();
} 


function debounce(func, wait = 1000) {
  let timeout;
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, wait);
  };
}
```

Testing:

```js
let deactivate = debounce(function() {
  document.querySelector('.mcont').classList.remove('active');
}),
 activate = function() {
  document.querySelector('.mcont').classList.add('active');
  deactivate();
} 


function debounce(func, wait = 1000) {
  let timeout;
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, wait);
  };
}
```

```css
.master {
 display: none;
 width: 100vw;
}

.mcont {
 padding: auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center;
}

.hover {
 height: 100vh;
}

.mtext {
 color: #ffffff;
 display: table;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 margin: auto;
 padding: 3vw;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

.mtext h1 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding-bottom: 1vh;
 font-size: 5vh;
}

.mtext p {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding-bottom: 2.5vh;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2vh;
}

.mtext button {
 background-color: #5555ff;
 border: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 15px 32px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 outline: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
 transition: background-color 2s;
}

.mtext button:hover {
 background-color: #55aaff;
}

.leftc, .rightc {
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 5vw;
 height: 5vw;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 vertical-align: middle;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 3vw;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
 transition: opacity 1s;
}

.active .hover > .leftc {
 opacity: 1.0;
}

.active .hover > .rightc {
 opacity: 1.0;
}

.leftc {
 left: 1vw;
}

.rightc {
 right: 1vw;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='mcont' onmousemove="activate()">
  <img class='master' src />
 <div class='hover'>
  <button class='leftc'>&lt;</button>
  <button class='rightc'>></button>
  <div class='mtext'>
   <h1>Slideshow</h1>
   <p>Buttons to left and right!</p>
   <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** props for the above vanilla `debounce()` go to [Vanilla debounce](https://gist.github.com/peduarte/7ee475dd0fae1940f857582ecbb9dc5f#file-index-js). If you need them, you might try fancier versions:

- with jQuery flavor: https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce
- [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#debounce)'s (has `leading`, `trailing` & `maxWait` params).

Comment: The table is pretty helpful, and the solution works _way_ better than my pitiful attempts at a Javascript solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think keyframes would be enough:

```
.hover:hover {
 animation-name: slideshowcursor;
 animation-duration: .5s;
 animation-delay: 2s; //that period
 animation-fill-mode: forwards
}
.hover:hover > .rightc, .hover:hover > .leftc {
 animation-name: slideshowarrows;
 animation-duration: .5s;
 animation-delay: 2s; //that period
 animation-fill-mode: forwards
}
@keyframes slideshowcursor {
 0% {
  height: 100vh;
 }
 100% {
  cursor: none;
 }
 }

@keyframes slideshowarrows {
 0% {
  border-radius: 50%;
width: 5vw;
height: 5vw;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
vertical-align: middle;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 3vw;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
transition: opacity 1s;
 }
 100% {
  display: none;
 }
 }
```

Note: I'm on my mobile now, so my testing is limited, but it should theoretically work.

Comment: Is `cursor` animatable?

Comment: Cursor by itself is not animatable, but 'cursor: none' should work fine

Comment: But you can somewhere downlosd .gif cursor and do this 'cursor: url("your-image.gif")'

Comment: Cursor blinks and reappears.

Comment: actually I don't know how it is possible, I'm now testing it and it works fine, it just disappears and stays disappeard. Do you have in 0% in slideshowcursor CSS of .hover ??

Comment: I tested with exact Copy/Paste

Comment: @Sen, `display` is not [animatable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). Besides, it seems you haven't read the question in detail. OP wants to cancel/override the `:hover` state styles a while after the mouse has stopped moving, even if the `:hover` is still active. You can't do that with CSS alone.